# Get HTML element via string

Tags: javascript, html, string

I want to grab an HTML element using a variable which contains a string which is also the name of my HTML element. When calling the variable containing the string I don´t want to get the string itself but the ID of the HTML element which has the same name. 
How can I do that?

In particular, I want to do this:

I´ve got some objects:

```
<canvas width="250" height="250" id="output_1"></canvas>
<canvas width="250" height="250" id="output_2"></canvas>
<canvas width="250" height="250" id="output_3"></canvas>
```

In the script I make a string which equals the ID:

```
var aktuellerCanvas;
var count = -1;
```

Later, I want to grab the elements by ID, first "output_1", then "output_2" and so on....
I tried this, but I was not successful. I guess, I´m only calling the string in the variable aktuellerCanvas.

```
count++;
aktuellerCanvas = "output_" + (count % 3 ++);

aktuellerCanvas.putImageData(image, 0, 0, 0, 0, width, height);
```

Can you help me?

Comment: your `aktuellerCanvas` is just a string, not a html element

Comment: document.getElementById("output_" + (count % 3 ++))?

Comment: `count % 3 ++` is not legal. You probably meant `++count % 3`.

Comment: as count is incremented before I don't think it is required at all

Answer (score 1):

You can use [document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) here because, it you have the id of the element as the string

```
aktuellerCanvas = document.getElementById("output_" + (count % 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

`aktuellerCanvas = document.getElementById("output_" + (count % 3 ++))`

Also
`(count % 3 ++)` is not valid

You may need `(count++ % 3 )` or `(++count % 3)`

Answer (score 0):

```
aktuellerCanvas = document.getElementById("output_" + (count++ % 3));
```

will do the job !

But caution, you cannot apply "putImageData" directly on the HTML element, you have to apply it on its 2D context ! See the code below:

```
var ctx = aktuellerCanvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.putImageData(image, 0, 0, 0, 0, width, height);
```

Comment: The W3School doc about "PutImageData": http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_putimagedata.asp

Answer (score 0):

If the ids are in the range of `[1, 3]` the code to return the element identifier name should be this:

```
aktuellerCanvasId = "output_" + (++count % 3 + 1);
```

Assuming you start with `count == -1`, the above statement will return `output_1` the first time you call it, `output_2` for the second time and `output_3` for the third; and then it repeats.

Afterwards you get the actual element using `getElementById()`:

```
aktuellerCanvas = document.getElementById(aktuellerCanvasId);
```